# For loop vs. class-object... How can I solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, for-loop

today I tried to create a class. 
I wrote this.

```
from first_names_class import firstnames
from last_names_class1 import lastnames
from object_name_list import my_new_list

class MyClass:
    """A Class with automatated full names."""
    # Automatically create the instances of the class named user_indexfrom the rangeiterator
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

for i in range(0, 49):
    my_new_list[i] = MyClass(firstnames[i], lastnames[i])

print(user1.first_name)
```

However, when I run it it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50']
>     File "/Users/myname/Documents/University/Programming for Quantitive Analysis/MyFirstClass.py", line 15, in 
>       print(user1.first_name)
>   NameError: name 'user1' is not defined
>   ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5', 'user6', 'user7', 'user8', 'user9', 'user10', 'user11', 'user12', 'user13', 'user14', 'user15', 'user16', 'user17', 'user18', 'user19', 'user20', 'user21', 'user22', 'user23', 'user24', 'user25', 'user26', 'user27', 'user28', 'user29', 'user30', 'user31', 'user32', 'user33', 'user34', 'user35', 'user36', 'user37', 'user38', 'user39', 'user40', 'user41', 'user42', 'user43', 'user44', 'user45', 'user46', 'user47', 'user48', 'user49', 'user50']

My thoughts on this: 
I don't know if I'm correct but I have read in another thread that the object/instance of the class should not be indented as it will be read "as content of the class".

On the other hand, the for-loop requires me to have this text indented.

How can I solve this problem, if that what I said is exactly the problem.

If what I said, is wrong, how can I then solve this NameError.

Maybe it has something to do with the list from which I take the object-name. As they are strings, maybe that is the trouble-maker.

I'd be thankful for any hint on how I can solve this.

Comment: `user1` is not defined anywhere in your code - that is what the `NameError` is telling you. Did you mean to access one of the values in `my_new_list`.

Comment: In the future, could you please paste error messages into code blocks, rather than as a quote. This way, the lines of the message will be separated, making it much easier to read.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I see. Well that was what I was trying to do with the for-loop.
Create them and assign the first names and surnames was my plan.

I created objects like this before and it worked with this code. 
random_user = MyClass("Karl", "Eggers")
print(random_user.last_name)

If the for loop does not do the job, how can I then create the objects, followed by assigning the first and last names?

Comment: @Billy there's nothing wrong with a `for` loop. As I said, the problem is using a variable name that isn't assigned a value anywhere. Python doesn't know what you mean by `user1` - and to be honest I'm not sure either. But you must know what you mean - just define in code what `user1` is.

Comment: It is supposed to be an instance of the class. What do you mean is unclear there? An instance to which I want to assign fields containing the last and first name of someone. 
Is that not the correct lingo?

Comment: I mean I'm unclear as to what value `user1` is supposed to hold. You haven't defined this in your code, so no-one knows other than you - least of all the Python interpreter (which is why it complains). The only instances of the class which you made are entries in `my_new_list`, and you haven't assigned them to any other variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Access elements of your list using index notation:

```py
print(my_new_list[0].first_name)
```

And there is nothing wrong with your indentation.

You never defined the symbol `user1`... You only have `my_new_list` which is of type `list`, which you can access the elements of using `[id]`.

Answer (score 0):

I used some pseudo lists to demonstrate but with this setup you would access the values like so

```
first = ['vash', 'billy']
last = ['stampede', 'stack']

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name):
        self.first_name = f_name
        self.last_name = l_name
        self.full_name = f_name + ' ' + l_name

user = [MyClass(first[idx], last[idx]) for idx, item in  enumerate(first)]

print(user[0].first_name)
print(user[1].first_name)
[print(user[idx].full_name) for idx, item in enumerate(user)]
```

> ```
> ~/python/stackoverflow/9.23$ python3.7 dicta.py
> vash
> billy
> vash stampede
> billy stack
> ```